# Mostrar las posiciones pares e impares de un vector

Tags: c

En este código de vectores que hice, lo que quiero específicamente es que muestre primero los elementos que esten en posiciones pares y después los que esten en posiciones impares.

Mi problema es que no he hallado cómo hacerlo, ya que solamente he logrado que indique el tipo de posiciones una por una, en vez de agrupado.

Es decir, quiero que sea:

*posiciones pares: 0,2,4*

*posiciones impares: 1,3,5*

En vez de:

*posición par:0*

*posición impar:1*

*posición par:2*

¿Cómo lo podría hacer?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
# define n 5

int main(void)
{
   int valores[n];
   int i;

   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
       printf("Da los valores de %d horas: \n", i);
       scanf("%d", &valores[i]);
   } 
   
   printf("\nLos numeros del vector son:\n");

   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
       printf("%d\n", valores[i]);
   }

   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
  
       if (i%2==0)
       {
           printf("\nLos pares: %d\n", valores[i]);      
       }
       else
           printf("Los impares: %d", valores[i]);   
    }

    getch();
}
```

Comment: Puedes hacer 2 bucles a la hora de mostrar. Ambos que se incrementen en 2 (`i+2`). Uno que empiece en `i=0` para los pares, y el otro en `i=1` para los impares. Si haces esto ten cuidado con el límite, ya que tendrás que recorrer la mitad de elementos de los que tiene el array completo.

Comment: Buen día, deseas imprimir los índices pares e impares o los valores del arreglo en las posiciones de los índices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te interesan los valores en las posiciones pares, es decir, los que se encuentran en las posiciones 0, 2, 4, ... eso es un bucle:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i+=2)
    printf("%d ", valores[i]);
```

A continuación quieres imprimir los valores de las posiciones impares ... más de lo mismo. el único cambio es que en vez de empezar en `i=0`, empiezas en `i=1`:

```
for(int i=1; i<n; i+=2)
    printf("%d ", valores[i]);
```